# Best Practice Unity, to create different scripts or use switch-cases?

Tags: c#, performance, unity-game-engine, game-engine, unityscript

I'm developing a game on unity.
Where there are units, with different functionalities but somehow same attributes.

What should i do?

create different script for each kind or make single with switch-cases and functions accordingly ?

What is the best practice to do?

Thanks in advance :)

for example: i have an angry guy and a calm guy, i have one basic inheritance of a person class, but inherited to the same class like unit, but in that i have different switch cases to determine angry , happy , calm and etc. should i make different classes for each of this is the right way to do ?

Comment: unity uses a component based approach, id stick with it. the instant gain is reuseability as long as your components are general enough (ofc some wont be, but many can be. for readability and ease of finding your way around the project, dont overdo it though ^^)

Comment: yeah have used the component approach :)
for example: i have an angry guy and a calm guy, i have one basic inheritance of a person class, but inherited to the same class like unit, but in that i have different switch cases to determine angry , happy , calm and etc. should i make different classes for each of this is the right way to do ?

Comment: i wonder if angry, calm and what other emotional states your units can be in, isnt much more than a variable actually.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about using Inheritance? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173149.aspx

```
public abstract class BaseUnit{

   public void virtual DoSomething(){
         // some default code
   }     
}

public class MyUnitType : BaseUnit{
  public override void DoSomething(){
     // my custom code if I do no want the default logic
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I'd also use inheritance. The only thing to keep in mind in Unity is that when inheriting from a child of MonoBehaviour you have to call base.Start(), base.Update(), and all the MonoBehaviour events manually. Also, @AnamtaKhan google Interfaces as well, it's gonna come handy sooner or later!

Comment: Yup i include the inheritance in my options too.
Should i use inheritance and use separate scripts for all kinds of units ?
One of my seniors asked me to make a single script and work with switch cases, but i'm not sure if thats the right way to do :s

Comment: components, components, components. and inbetween some classes and structs for holding data or passing it around. at least thats the intended use - but its <insert language>, you can do whatever rocks your boat. but its meant to be seen as, you dont really need a unit as class and series of derived classes, but merely as concept of interconnected components (and its data). well at least thats how i understood it ;)

Comment: yeah have done everything as components.
for example: i have an angry guy and a calm guy, i have one basic inheritance of a person class, but inherited to the same class like unit, but in that i have different switch cases to determine angry , happy , calm and etc. should i make different classes for each of this is the right way to do ?

Comment: @AnamtaKhan Could u share with us a little bit of your code? Then it would be easier to give a feedback and possible solutions....

Comment: @AnamtaKhan i think you should make different prefabs, not different/derived classes. or is it about how to transfer from one state (happy) to another (angry)?